# What is the correct way of using a many-to-many relation with the same model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm trying to use a many to many relation on the same Eloquent model. The model represents one item in the store and could be related to many other items.

This is the current migration of the `RelatedItem` model:

```php
Schema::create('related_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['item_id', 'related_id']);
            $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items');
            $table->integer('related_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('related_id')->references('id')->on('items');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And this is the relation in the `Item` model:

```php
public function related()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'related_items', "related_id");
    }
```

I've created some relations trough the `DatabaseSeeder` that injects these records into my database:

```php
DB::table('related_items')->insert([
            'item_id' => 0,
            'related_id' => 1,
        ]);
        DB::table('related_items')->insert([
            'item_id' => 0,
            'related_id' => 2,
        ]);
```

I expected to get the 2 related items, but instead got the item with id 0 (which is the item the relation is being called from) twice.

Am I doing something wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `related_id` as the *fourth* argument:

```php
public function related()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'related_items', null, 'related_id');
}
```